# psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed on FastAPI

Tags: python, psycopg2, fastapi

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693805/how-to-use-fastapi-and-psycopg2-without-orm) to create a connection using psycopg2. It works on the first call on the endpoint. The second try gives this error `psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed`. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
from config import conn
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""
            select ... 
            """
            )
            pos = cursor.fetchone()

            cursor.execute("""
            select ...' 
            """
            )
            neg = cursor.fetchone()

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're closing the connection in the last line of your code, it cannot be used further (when calling the endpoint for the second time) without reconnecting.

You can either delete the last line (which would result in never closing connection) and move conn.close() to [app shutdown event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#shutdown-event) or perform `psycopg2.connect` each time you need it.